# Best practice to deploy python app to use a specific version of Python with venv

Tags: python, git, python-venv

I am done with a project and it has been been pushed to git but the client wants VENV. I already got `venv` to work and created a `requirements.txt` file.

My question is what is the best practice for a deployment workflow. So far this is what I created as a deploy workflow:

```
git clone ssh://myawesomerepo
cd myawesomerepo
pip install virtualenv
venv -python=python3.5 env
source env/bin/activate
pip install -r requirements.txt
python run.py
```

Is this the correct workflow?

**Assuming that we don't know what version of python the client has. My project is written for python 3.5, and if the client has 2.7 will this work?***

Comment: Workflow seems fine as long as you only want to run the code in Python3.5 on linux

Comment: Ya, OS is always Linux.  But this project req. python 3.5 it's why i added -python=python3.5. If the user has python 2.7 will venv install python3.5 locally?

Comment: You'd need to have python3.5 installed in order to create a Python3.5 Venv. Alternatives to not requiring anyone to install much extra things would be wrap your project in a Docker container.

Comment: Ok i will look into that ty

Answer (score 1):

I tend to you use the Anaconda package manager rather than venv, one of the nice features is that if you run

```
conda create -n myenv python=3.5
```

it will download and install Python 3.5 even if it's not installed on the system already.

Comment: Thank you, I will read into it . The problem is the client requested VENV. I tested VENV and it worked with several Python binaries that where not installed. I.e. 2.6 , 3.4 , but these are downgrades.